# Compile error at omCommand.cpp:3765 in SequoiaDB

Tags: distributed-database, sequoiadb

Describe the bug: Compile error at SequoiaDB/engine/omsvc/omCommand.cpp:3765

To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. git clone https://github.com/SequoiaDB/SequoiaDB.git
2. scons --engine
3. see error blow:

```
SequoiaDB/engine/omsvc/omCommand.cpp:3765:2: error: #endif without #if
    #endif
    ^
SequoiaDB/engine/omsvc/omCommand.cpp:9875:2: error: #endif without #if #endif
    ^
SequoiaDB/engine/omsvc/omCommand.cpp:10669:2: error: #endif without #if #endif // SDB_ENTERPRISE
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some mistake in the script remove code between SDB_ENTERPRISE macro before uploading to github. Now it is fixed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXEE7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93SyP.png)